# Windows Input Experience

Tags: boot, process

August 2023 - prevent 'Windows Input Experience' from loading?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you trying to end these processes? They are part of the OS. What problems are they causing for you that you think ending them will resolve?

Comment: What is your edit supposed to accomplish? It certainly didn’t add any details or clarity. The comments you put on the existing answer for example could go into the question body. As is, this question will not be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

These are [Windows Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service). They are part of Windows. Though you might not be able to *stop* an essential service, you can reduce the CPU time (impact on operation) by reducing its priority.

The following script sets StartMenuExperienceHost to a lower priority. Copy it to a batch (.bat) file and run it to reduce the impact of that service.

```
REM From https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/change-priority-of-win10-process-with-command-line/
wmic process where name="StartMenu.exe" CALL setpriority 64
wmic process where name="StartMenuExperienceHost.exe" CALL setpriority 64
```

You *can* disable the Smart Screen Filter *in windows Edge* with a tool such as O&O [ShutUp10](https://www.oo-software.com/en/shutup10). You could also [disable Windows Defender Smartscreen](https://winbuzzer.com/2020/11/23/how-to-disable-smartscreen-in-windows-10-xcxwbt/), but that **is a bad thing to do**, because it increases the chance of your computer being harmed by [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware).

Comment: I am fully aware of what smartscreen does, I am also aware that these processes are part of the OS.  This machine is used, almost exclusively, for running DCS (digital Combat Simulator) this simulator requires every last bit of RAM and processing power to run smoothly therefore I disable ALL non essential processes.
Windows Input Experience is the biggest user of RAM after my anti virus program.
Therefore I am not seeking advice simply a possible solution.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik - I have already tried the regedit method of disabling Smartscreen and it does not work with the current build of Win 11.

Comment: So?  No possible solutions then?